# HTML form stop redirect and allow PHP to call JavaScript from within the HTML file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to have a form on a HTML page not refresh when it's sent, which I've done, but I'd also like to allow the `echo` command in the PHP file to be able to call JavaScript from within the HTML file.

So far, all the `echo` commands aren't being carried out, which isn't what I expected.

Here's some code from the HTML and PHP files:

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function functionInFile() {
    alert("recieved");
}

    $(function() {  
      $(".postform").submit(function() {  
      var content = $(this).serialize();

      $.post('signup.php?', content);

      return false;

      });  
    });     

</script>
```

and the PHP:

```
echo '<script type=\'text/javascript\'>functionInFile()</script>';
```

So basically, I'd like the PHP file to be able to invoke a function in the HTML file, while not being redirected when I click submit.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: obviously the echo's aren't coming thru as you don't put the received information into the html document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the success callback of the `$.post()` to execute a function which your PHP passes back. Try this:

PHP

```
// do some stuff with the posted data
echo 'functionInFile'; // name of js function to execute in calling page
```

jQuery

```
function functionInFile() {
    alert("recieved");
}

$(function() {  
    $(".postform").submit(function() {  
        $.post(
            'signup.php?', 
            $(this).serialize(),
            function(func) {
                window[func]();
            },
            'text'
        );
        return false;
    });  
});
```

Comment: why not simply do: `$.post('signup.php?',$(this).serialize(),functionInFile);` using the functionInFile as callback directly?

Comment: That would work too. It depends on how many functions you need to run in the callback.

Comment: Thanks, but it's got to be called within PHP, as it's the script that's determining which function to call (more than one, that one was just one I wrote for this example). So I guess it's not a callback.. Sorry if I didn't make it clear.

Comment: Chrome doesn't seem to like the 'dataType: 'text'' line... Don't know why, everything I've tried won't work: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :'

Comment: Thanks so much, it's my first time using jQuery, as you could probably tell.

Comment: it should be noted that using JSON is a much better way to send simple data using ajax and is considered best practice just as "eval is evil"

Answer (score 1):

It could be better to use the callback function of `post`

> jQuery.post( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] [,
>   dataType] )

So you would execute what ever code is within the reply or pre determined login `onsusccess`

```
$.post( 'signup.php?', content,
      function( data ) {
          //data contains the reply of the post so you can 
          //exec the code like this using JavaScript
          //altogether eval is frowned upon because it is high overhead and opens
          //opens up to code injection or whatever
         //eval(data);
         //so you just execute whatever method you need
         functionInFile();
        //or you reply from server in json and converto tobject
        //reply: {'executeFunction': true}
       var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
       if (data.executeFunction == true) { functionInFile(); }

      }
    );
```

[ParseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

In order for PHP echo to work. the page MUST reload baecause it is server side.

A webpage cycle is SERVER SIDE, then Client side.

[SERVER] -> [CLIENT -> AJAX to SERVER -> SERVER REPLY ATTACH]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're sending the right `<script>` tag. XHR return values are treated as data though, not executable code. Luckily for you, jQuery has code to check if you insert a `<script>` tag into the dom and execute it. You should be able to just do:

```
$.post('signup.php?', content, function(html) {$(document).append(html);});
```

and your script will execute.

(I would recommend making this happen in a different way though. I've worked on Apps that send large portions of javascript back in AJAX calls, and it's a pain to debug. It would be much better to send back a JSON object with a string for the next action, then keep an object of "approved" actions as a string -> function lookup table.)